# What special privileges "/system/xbin/su" does have w.r.t. root access?

Tags: rooting, permissions, partitions, selinux

[This answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/96737/283827) says:

> Because of the way directory/file permissions are configured on
>   Android, you need to have the `su` binary on your `/system` partition
>   in order for it to work. Putting elsewhere will not suffice, because
>   it will not have the permissions it needs to actually allow processes
>   to switch users.

What is the mechanism that causes binaries in `/system` to have special privileges?
Specifically, if I moved `/system/xbin/su` to `/data/xbin/su` (and changed anything relevant to point to `/data/xbin/su` instead of `/system/xbin/su`), what would be different?

---

My guess is that these privileges are enforced by SELinux.
I searched Android's sources, and found in [platform/system/sepolicy/private/file_contexts](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/master/private/file_contexts):

```
/system(/.*)?       u:object_r:system_file:s0
```

and in [platform/system/sepolicy/public/domain.te](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/master/public/domain.te):

```
allow { appdomain coredomain } system_file:file { execute read open getattr map };
```

However, I also found in [platform/system/sepolicy/private/file_contexts](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/master/private/file_contexts):

```
/system/xbin/su     u:object_r:su_exec:s0
```

and in [platform/system/sepolicy/public/domain.te](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/master/public/domain.te):

```
# Nobody should be able to execute su on user builds.
# On userdebug/eng builds, only dumpstate, shell, and
# su itself execute su.
neverallow { domain userdebug_or_eng(`-dumpstate -shell -su') } su_exec:file no_x_file_perms;
```

So I am confused.

Answer (score 8):

Since Android is based on Linux kernel, getting root access by executing `/system/xbin/su` - like one can do on a Linux system - used to work in good old days but not now. The story is a bit twisted.

**WHAT IS SUID?**
Special thing about `/system/xbin/su` isn't that it's in `/system` partition, but the `set-user-ID-root (SUID)` bit set on this binary makes it special. [SUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid)  (**S**et owner **U**ser **ID** up on execution) is a special type of permission on Linux kernel that grants the permissions of the file owner to the new process rather than inheriting permissions from parent process who runs it. Since the owner of `/system/xbin/su` is root (UID 0), it can switch the effective UID of process to 0 when executed, hence enabling calling process to have root access.
This is a part of Discretionary Access Control (DAC); one of [Linux kernel's security features](https://www.linux.com/learn/overview-linux-kernel-security-features).

**MANDATORY ACCESS CONTROL (MAC):**
Implemented since KitKat, SELinux can control who executes `su` binary, by defining Access Vector rules.

On `userdebug`/`eng` build of a ROM, `adb shell` (by executing `su`, as you have [mentioned](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/android-9.0.0_r33/public/domain.te#1109)) and `adb daemon` <sup>([1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-9.0.0_r33/rootdir/init.usb.rc#15))</sup> can make `transition` <sup>([2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/android-9.0.0_r33/private/su.te#4), [3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/android-9.0.0_r33/private/file_contexts#245), [4](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/android-9.0.0_r42/private/adbd.te#12), [5](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/selinux/+/android-9.0.0_r33/secilc/docs/cil_type_statements.md#typetransition))</sup> to run as root with unrestricted context `u:r:su:s0` <sup>([6](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/android-9.0.0_r42/private/su.te#19))</sup>. But `adbd` can't be run as root on final `user` builds (<sup>[7](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-9.0.0_r33/adb/daemon/main.cpp#63), [8](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-9.0.0_r33/adb/Android.mk#348)</sup>), neither [su binary is included](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-9.0.0_r33/libcutils/fs_config.cpp#173). So, `/system/xbin/su` is intended only for developers to debug `eng`ineering or `userdebug` builds of a ROM, not for end user <sup>([9](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/update_engine/+/android-9.0.0_r33/hardware_android.cc#106))</sup>. And second special thing about it is its SELinux context `u:object_r:su_exec:s0`.

See [Why “adb root” does nothing?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213429/218526) for more details.

**HOW ANDROID RESTRICTS ROOT ACCESS?**
Keeping SELinux aside, on user build of a ROM that is intended for end users, placing `su` under `/system` won't give any advantage, even with `set-user-ID-root`. A normal app can't elevate its privileges to root by executing `su` because:

- Starting with [Jelly Bean](https://source.android.com/security/enhancements/enhancements43), Android switched to file capabilities (a capability is a subset of root privileges) instead of relying on `set-user-ID` type of security vulnerabilities. A more secure mechanism: [Ambient capabilities](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/ambient) has also been introduced in Android Oreo.
- System daemons and services can make use of file capabilities to gain process capabilities (see under [Transformation of capabilities during execve](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html)) but apps can't do that either because they run with process control attribute `NO_NEW_PRIVS` set, ignoring `set-user-ID` as well as file capabilities. SUID is also ignored by mounting `/system` and `/data` with `nosuid` option for all apps.
- UID can be switched only if calling process has [SETUID/SETGID](http://androidxref.com/kernel_3.18/xref/include/uapi/linux/capability.h#133) capability in its Bounding set (one of the 5 capabilities categories a process can have). But Android apps are made to run with all capabilities already dropped in all sets.
- Starting with Oreo, apps' ability to change UID/GID has been further suppressed by [blocking certain syscalls](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/android-9.0.0_r33/libc/SECCOMP_BLACKLIST_APP.TXT#31) using [seccomp filters](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/07/seccomp-filter-in-android-o.html).

ADB daemon, however runs with [CAP_SETUID and CAP_SETGID](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-9.0.0_r33/adb/daemon/main.cpp#123) (to allow switching to UID/GID `shell`???). But `adb shell` too can't get us capabilities by executing a SUID-root `su` binary because `NOROOT` and `NO_SETUID_FIXUP` [security bits are set](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/minijail/+/android-9.0.0_r33/libminijail.c#2029) on `adbd` process. Contrarily on a debugging build, no capabilities are dropped from bounding set <sup>([10](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-9.0.0_r42/adb/daemon/main.cpp#53))</sup>, so executing `/system/xbin/su` (with `set-user-ID-root` bit or `cap_setuid,cap_setgid+ep` file capabilities) would get us full root access.

Syscalls used in these sandboxing methods: `cap_set_proc`, `setresuid`, `setresgid`, `sys_seccomp`, `prctl` (CAPBSET_DROP, SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS, SET_SECUREBITS, SET_SECCOMP) are all part of [Minijail](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/minijail/#what-is-it).

---

Summarizing the above lines, DAC and MAC would only allow `adb root` and executing `/system/xbin/su` from `adb shell` on `userdebug` build of ROM. To have root access from apps and on `user` builds targeted for end user, we need to ***root the phone*** as explained below.

---

**HOW TO GET ROOT ACCESS ON ANDROID?**
So if we want to have privileges with UID 0 and all 38 capabilities of Linux kernel, we need a rooting solution that can deal with all above described security measures. Since the standalone `su` binaries stopped working with the release of Jelly Bean, [a transition was made to su daemon mode](https://chainfire.eu/articles/768).

Now on a rooted phone, a fully privileged daemon runs from the very start of booting process (in fact `init` is replaced). When an app needs root access, it executes [su binary provided by the rooting solution](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=23432367&postcount=9). This `su` doesn't change UID/GID on its own, but just [connects to super user daemon](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/master/native/jni/su/su.cpp#L187) through a UNIX socket and asks to provide the requesting app a root shell with all capabilities. In order to interact with user to grant/deny `su` requests from apps, su daemon is hooked with an app that can display user interface prompts. A database of granted/denied permissions is built by su daemon for future use.
In addition to that, SELinux denials are also handled by defining SELinux policy allow-rules when rooting the phone.

New methods of root like Magisk work in system-less mode i.e. without modifying `/system` partition. Only boot partition - that contains kernel and initramfs - is modified to inject su daemon service and new SELiux policies. A locked bootloader won't boot modified `boot.img`, so bootloader needs to be unlocked. For more details regarding this, see [Unlocking Bootloader](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/info-boot-process-android-vs-linux-t3785254). However there have been some rooting hacks that worked by bypassing above described security implementations without going for proper way of rooting. Most of such exploits and vulnerabilities in Android OS have been fixed over time. Here is a good [write up](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205707/218526) on this subject.

So to conclude, placing `su` binary under `/system` or any other location won't give any benefit.

Also see [How Magisk works?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213344/218526) for more details.

**PS:** Please ignore so many links, they are for my own future reference.

Comment: any way to get root access in an app on a user_debug build? executing `/system/xbin/su` fails due to selinux, even with permissive mode!

Comment: @Paschalis nothing can fail due to SELinux in permissive mode. But it's not only the SELinux which causes `/system/xbin/su` to fail. The bigger problems are `NO_NEW_PRIVS` attribute and dropped capabilities for all app processes. That's why we need a background daemon. Answer to your query is already there: *"To have root access from apps ... we need to **root the phone**"*.

Comment: TWRP isn't available for android 10, and booting into it fails to mount `/system`. And magisk patching of `boot.img` breaks as soon as I modify stuff at `/system/lib64` and `/system/bin/`. I wonder if you could spare some time to discuss this over a chat. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Paschalis I have been too lazy to switch to Android 10 so far. So I'm afraid I'd be able to help you on things specific to Android 10.

Comment: the way to go was `magisk modules`. I don't have to modify /system/. I just create some modules that override or extend /system. And it works wonders on a factory image. The only reason someone might want to modify `/system` thesedays it's if he/she uses an app that relies to /system modifications.

Comment: @Paschalis I run a Linux environment on my device. Linux tools are often using `/etc` to save configurations (if not modified to use some other location). So I find it easy to just make `/system` partition (where `/etc` lives) R/W rather than bind mounting (like Magisk does). So it depends on priorities and situations.