# Do I Need a Super User app on a rooted phone?

Tags: root-access, superuser

Our company uses a few devices for in house tasks.
I have the SU binary flashed to my devices. I have proprieteary apps installed that access the SU through hardcoded shell commands. My devices are completeley locked and cannot install new apps (no package installer, custom recovery, and re-engineered USB ports) so I don't really have any security concerns.
At the present we rely on a 3rd party SuperUser app to grant privaleges to our own apps. Is there a way to Automatically grant SU priveleage to all the apps on the device (we trust them all - because we wrote them) without prompting the user?
Understanding that a few SU apps do have a feature to "allow all" I still ask because I would like to avoid using 3rd party software completely.

Can I just remove the SU app, or do I need to write a replacement?

Comment: From where did you get the `su` binary?

Comment: flashed it from a zip before we installed our own recovery

Comment: And who provided that zip?

Comment: Pulled it from [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2291865) , worked for us.

Comment: I think you can Allow All and then delete the su app...

Comment: Also, you probably just need build you own SU app... One that does nothing.

Comment: @sh7411usa those must be really old devices if just placing su binary elevates root privileges. Starting with JB, it went on getting harder and harder. Anyway, granted/denied su requests are managed by UI app and usually stored in a file somewhere. The latest rooting solution Magisk, for instance, stores its settings in SQLite database file `/data/adb/magisk.db`. You need to figure that out to make `su` work without UI app. I'm not sure how strongly this old `su` binary is hooked to the UI app.

Comment: Answered [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207902/218526)

Comment: @Irfan Latif - having read your link, would that imply that on ICS (yup! our devices are that old) we would need a root permissions manager?

Comment: @sh7411usa not necessarily. You need to find some `su` binary that works independently without permission manager app. I'm not sure if any such working thing exists. Another workaround would be to create a database or config file (wherever `su` saves permission granted/denied policy) for all possibly installed apps and put that database on all devices.