# How does SuperSU check if a phone is rooted?

Tags: rooting, root-access, 8.0-oreo, superuser, supersu

I have a rooted custom device (Android 8.0), I can use `adb` and run `su` and do whatever I want in the shell. But SuperSU or any other app cannot find root. I have made a symlink from `/system/xbin/su` to `/system/bin/su` but it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/system/xbin/su` is a normal [`su`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html) binary that's shipped with `userdebug` or `eng`ineering builds of ROMs. It gets you root access by making syscall [`setuid`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setuid.2.html). On the other hand, with SuperSU or Magisk root, a [special binary](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=23432367&postcount=9) is placed at `/system/bin/su` (or some other path) which works quite differently. For details see [How Magisk works?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213344/218526).

So, with only a working `/system/xbin/su` executable, your device isn't essentially *"rooted"*. SuperSU or Magisk won't work with this binary. And so the apps cannot get root access.

**RELATED:** [What special privileges “/system/xbin/su” does have w.r.t. root access?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207902/218526)