# How can I install SuperSu on a pre-rooted Android head unit?

Tags: rooting, root-access, supersu, automotive-head-unit

I am working on a pre-rooted Android head unit. I can do "adb root" or "adb shell su" using wifi adb. So there is root access and Su binary on the device. But I can't use root applications because there is no app to grant root access. I have tried installing supersu or superuser on /system/app. I made it install the apps but they say "device not rooted" when I try to run them.

So how can I make supersu see my su binary?

Comment: If an app is required depends on the su binary. If the su binary just grants root permissions without interaction in an app, then you don't need such an app. But it may be possible that the su binary is only usable via adb and not from within apps. You may need to install SuperSu or similar and then replace thee existing su binary with the one from SuperSu (better not remove the original su binary just rename it just to make sure you dont loose root permissions at all).

Comment: *...but they say "device not rooted"...*. See [How does SuperSU check if a phone is rooted?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216188/218526).

Comment: Also related regarding `adb root` and `adb shell su`: [How to grant certain apps root permission through ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/225313/44325)